# GSON seems to fail to parse JSON string

Tags: json, parsing, java-8, gson

Attempting to parse a JSON string with GSON is failing. I'm using JDK 8, GSON V2.10.1 (with IntelliJ, also VS Code) and identified the source of the error. The relevant code snippets are given below:

The JSON:

```json
{
  "took" : 2,
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 19,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "layouts-new",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "a0b8707c-feb3-4867-966d-33c435c82141",
        "_score" : 1.0,
         . . .
```

The code snippet I wrote:

```java
      Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
      JSONObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(json, JSONObject.class);
      . . .
```

The jsonObject returned is {}, empty. That means none of the elements from the JSON was parsed. Debugged and found the offending line to be `BoundField field = boundFields.get(name)`. It threw an NPE. That source code comes from the method `public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException` of `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java` from the package `com.google.gson.internal.bind`.

```java
      try {
        in.beginObject();
        while (in.hasNext()) {
          String name = in.nextName();
          BoundField field = boundFields.get(name);
          if (field == null || !field.deserialized) {
            in.skipValue();
          } else {
            readField(accumulator, in, field);
          }
        }
      } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
```

Any idea what could be the culprit or where am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSONObject` is not from the Gson library. Due to this Gson has no built-in adapter for it and tries to use reflection for deserialization, using the internal fields of that `JSONObject` class.

Use the corresponding Gson class [`com.google.gson.JsonObject`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html) instead:

```java
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
```